Find the test plan name which is associated with the test suite in Azure DevOps
How to find the test plan name which is associated with the test suite? I have only test suite Id but dont remember under which test plan this test suite is created.
I am expecting to find the Test plan name associated with the test suite i created.

Is the answer below working for you? @arunsivaraj

Not sure what kind of solution you are looking for. If it's a one-time thing you could do it like this with the DevOps API and run it from your browser console.
It first fetches all test plans. Then loops through them and checks in which plan the suite is included
(async () => {
    const organization = 'ORG_NAME';
    const project      = 'PROJECT_NAME';
    const pat          = 'DEVOPS_PAT';
    const testSuiteId  = 123456;

    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(':' + pat));
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: headers,
        redirect: 'follow'
    };

    try {
        let plans = [];
        let continuationToken = null;

        do {
            const url = `https://dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/testplan/plans?api-version=7.1${continuationToken ? `&continuationToken=${continuationToken}` : ''}`;
            const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions);
            const result = await response.json();
            plans = plans.concat(result.value);
            continuationToken = response.headers.get('x-ms-continuationtoken');
        } while (continuationToken);

        for (const plan of plans) {
            const suiteUrl = `https://dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/testplan/Plans/${plan.id}/suites/${testSuiteId}?api-version=7.1`;
            const suiteResponse = await fetch(suiteUrl, requestOptions);

            if (suiteResponse.ok) {
                console.log(`Found Test Suite ID ${testSuiteId} in Test Plan: ${plan.name}`);
                return;
            }
        }
        console.log(`Test Suite ID ${testSuiteId} not found in any test plan.`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('There was a problem with the fetch operation:', error);
    }
})();

